Extracting the values of Fipy diffusion and convection terms
I am new to Fipy and I was wondering if there is a way how to extract the values of a diffusion or convections terms. in the case of a cell variable this is easy but  diffusion or convections are in fact only representation of the these quantities that does not hols any values. How can one evaluate the diffusion/convection terms ? .. something like ConvectionTerm(..).evaluate
I tries many attempts but it seems to me that the only way is to use .faceGrad and .divergence methods explicitly on the solving variables to estimate the diffusion/convection terms, something I would like to avoid !

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

There really isn't a way to do this, in part because it's not really clear what it would mean. A FiPy DiffusionTerm or ConvectionTerm doesn't really have a "value"; instead, it makes entries in the solution matrix. var.faceGrad.divergence will give you an idea of how the term will contribute to the change in value, but it won't be exactly what the FiPy term does, especially for convection terms.
It is possible to see the solution matrix, both overall and term-by-term, using the FIPY_DISPLAY_MATRIX environment variable.

I have found a work around using matrix representations of operators in Fipy!
def getNumValueOfTerm(term,solver): 

   matrix = term._buildMatrix(var=term.var,SparseMatrix=solver._matrixClass)[1]
   numValue = np.dot(matrix.numpyArray , term.var.numericValue)
   return CellVariable(mesh=term.var.mesh,value=numValue)

def getcurrent(solvingVar,solver):
  currentDen=DiffusionTerm(var=solvingVar,coeff=elecDiffFace)
  return  getNumValueOfTerm(currentDen,solver)

valueOFCurrent=getcurrent(solvingVar,solver)

I hope this will help the users in Future! if you have any criticism about this approach i will be every happy to see!
